# OSError: mysql_config not found at installing mysqldb 1.3.7 on Fedora

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, fedora

For a project I have to install a specific version of `mysqlclient==1.3.7` . However I get errors: it seems that `mysql_config` is missing:

```
(venv) [ac@localmachine data-tools]$ python -m pip install mysqlclient==1.3.7
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.7
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz (79 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-dt7pv4kk
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    /bin/sh: line 1: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tso5g_cy/mysqlclient_4957ca0023294aaf907cc37f2312dd8c/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/ff/4e964e20b559e55d7afa60fbccc6a560f2adf289813bd3d7eb4eb8a87093/mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz#sha256=c74a83b4cb2933d0e43370117eeebdfa03077ae72686d2df43d31879267f1f1b (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient==1.3.7 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11rc1, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0rc3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2.post1, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient==1.3.7
```

So I installed `community-mysql-devel` and reruned it:

```
(venv) [ac@localmachine data-tools]$ python -m pip install mysqlclient==1.3.7
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.7
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz (79 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for mysqlclient, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7okc9y_x/mysqlclient_b4db68125912451d81875f39d142c9ee/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7okc9y_x/mysqlclient_b4db68125912451d81875f39d142c9ee/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-znhsqlja/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/include/site/python3.9/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7okc9y_x/mysqlclient_b4db68125912451d81875f39d142c9ee/
    Complete output (35 lines):
    /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:691: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'distribution-name' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'distribution_name' instead
      warnings.warn(
    /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:691: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'build-requires' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'build_requires' instead
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,7,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.7 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/_mysql.o -m64
    _mysql.c:29:10: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
       29 | #include "my_config.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/bin/python -u -c 
'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'/tmp/pip-install 7okc9y_x/mysqlclient_b4db68125912451d81875f39d142c9ee/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install okc9y_x/mysqlclient_b4db68125912451d81875f39d142c9ee/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-znhsqlja/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/include/site/python3.9/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

As wheel seemed to lack, I tried to install it as well:

```
(venv) [ac@localmachine data-tools]$ python -m pip install wheel
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.36.2
```

But it wasn't sufficient

```
(venv) [ac@localmachine data-tools]$ python -m pip install mysqlclient==1.3.7
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.7
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz (79 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6n9fzb6y/mysqlclient_c3d7b33fbad748f1b57a8ca294cb6ea1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6n9fzb6y/mysqlclient_c3d7b33fbad748f1b57a8ca294cb6ea1/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-_20ndtkd
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-6n9fzb6y/mysqlclient_c3d7b33fbad748f1b57a8ca294cb6ea1/
  Complete output (35 lines):
  /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:691: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'distribution-name' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'distribution_name' instead
    warnings.warn(
  /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:691: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'build-requires' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'build_requires' instead
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  ...
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -... I/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/_mysql.o -m64
  _mysql.c:29:10: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
     29 | #include "my_config.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
 ...
    _mysql.c:29:10: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
       29 | #include "my_config.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6n9fzb6y/mysqlclient_c3d7b33fbad748f1b57a8ca294cb6ea1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6n9fzb6y/mysqlclient_c3d7b33fbad748f1b57a8ca294cb6ea1/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-9xyqzh6s/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/include/site/python3.9/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

## Update

I made sure that it was alright:

```
(venv) [ac@localmachine data-tools]$ python -m pip install mysqlclient==1.3.7
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.7
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz (79 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oc0b_tf0/mysqlclient_3c668220085e4790813f0fbf24ad3d06/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oc0b_tf0/mysqlclient_3c668220085e4790813f0fbf24ad3d06/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-0vacq2_s
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-oc0b_tf0/mysqlclient_3c668220085e4790813f0fbf24ad3d06/
  Complete output (81 lines):
  /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:697: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'distribution-name' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'distribution_name' instead
    warnings.warn(
  /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:697: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'build-requires' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'build_requires' instead
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,7,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.7 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/_mysql.o
  In file included from _mysql.c:29:
  /usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
      3 | #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
        |  ^~~~~~~
  _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_server_init’:
  _mysql.c:275:27: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    275 |                         s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(item);
        |                           ^
  _mysql.c:305:27: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    305 |                         s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(item);
        |                           ^
  _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize’:
  _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
        |                ^
  _mysql.c:600:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
    600 |                 _stringsuck(ca, value, ssl);
        |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
        |                ^
  _mysql.c:601:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
    601 |                 _stringsuck(capath, value, ssl);
        |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
        |                ^
  _mysql.c:602:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
    602 |                 _stringsuck(cert, value, ssl);
        |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
        |                ^
  _mysql.c:603:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
    603 |                 _stringsuck(key, value, ssl);
        |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
        |                ^
  _mysql.c:604:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
    604 |                 _stringsuck(cipher, value, ssl);
        |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
  _mysql.c:1968:48: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
   1968 |         if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
        |                                                ^
  _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_getattro’:
  _mysql.c:2675:15: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   2675 |         cname = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(name);
        |               ^
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oc0b_tf0/mysqlclient_3c668220085e4790813f0fbf24ad3d06/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oc0b_tf0/mysqlclient_3c668220085e4790813f0fbf24ad3d06/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-yhrboba8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/include/site/python3.9/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-oc0b_tf0/mysqlclient_3c668220085e4790813f0fbf24ad3d06/
    Complete output (81 lines):
    /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:697: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'distribution-name' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'distribution_name' instead
      warnings.warn(
    /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:697: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'build-requires' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'build_requires' instead
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,7,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.7 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/_mysql.o
    In file included from _mysql.c:29:
    /usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
        3 | #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
          |  ^~~~~~~
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_server_init’:
    _mysql.c:275:27: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
      275 |                         s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(item);
          |                           ^
    _mysql.c:305:27: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
      305 |                         s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(item);
          |                           ^
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize’:
    _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
      589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
          |                ^
    _mysql.c:600:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
      600 |                 _stringsuck(ca, value, ssl);
          |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
      589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
          |                ^
    _mysql.c:601:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
      601 |                 _stringsuck(capath, value, ssl);
          |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
      589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
          |                ^
    _mysql.c:602:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
      602 |                 _stringsuck(cert, value, ssl);
          |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
      589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
          |                ^
    _mysql.c:603:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
      603 |                 _stringsuck(key, value, ssl);
          |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:589:16: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
      589 |         if(t){d=PyUnicode_AsUTF8(t);Py_DECREF(t);}\
          |                ^
    _mysql.c:604:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_stringsuck’
      604 |                 _stringsuck(cipher, value, ssl);
          |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
    _mysql.c:1968:48: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
     1968 |         if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
          |                                                ^
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_getattro’:
    _mysql.c:2675:15: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     2675 |         cname = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(name);
          |               ^
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oc0b_tf0/mysqlclient_3c668220085e4790813f0fbf24ad3d06/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oc0b_tf0/mysqlclient_3c668220085e4790813f0fbf24ad3d06/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-yhrboba8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/include/site/python3.9/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/mysql_config` is provided by one of these Fedora packages: `mariadb-connector-c-devel`  or `community-mysql-devel`

Comment: I updated the question @KnudLarsen , but I still have the same errors ...

Comment: Better stick to "mariadb" packages : Your **new error** = `fatal error: my_config.h: No such file ...` ,,,, ,,, i.e. my_config.h is provided by maridb → `yum install mariadb-devel` ......... Please use yum to decide package names : `yum provides */my_config.h` ......... `yum provides */mysql_config`

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps to get it working...

Added the MySQL repo to Fedora:

`sudo dnf install https://repo.mysql.com//mysql80-community-release-fc31-1.noarch.rpm`

Installed MySQL:

`sudo dnf install mysql-community-server`

Installed the development headers:

`sudo dnf install mysql-community-devel`